# How much memory does a VNC server use?

Tags: linux, memory, vnc

I have a `VNC server` started on my linux machine. How much memory does a VNC server use?

If I create multiple `VNC servers` on same machine and do not use few of them for long time. Being an unused process, does operating system shift them to heap area and free the memory?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question is as,

VNC protocal works on frame buffer technique (every time screen frame data is sent to remote client which is your machine in this case) memory required for such frame buffer would be in MB's (<10 mb in most cases which depends on X11 server settings on your machine) but VNC application also stores its binaries in memory which also takes some memory.

typical memory usage of VNC can be found out using monitoring utilities like top,ps etc.

for 2nd question answer could be, frame buffer is used only when client demands for it till then no operation happens other than keeping session alive which needs only binary and session data which is very less.

hope this helps :)

Comment: We have server machines which run out of memory when 6-7 VNC servers are started. This happens even if we don't use session. Are there any more programs included in a typical VNC startup?

Comment: there could be 2 reasons , 
1.check memory utilization of vnc programs on your machine, really only vnc application is eating all the memory or any other application is also a culprit
2.your server memory is quite less